# How to install tomcat server in centos?

Tags: centos, tomcat, installation

I'm new to server's technologies.Please suggest me how to install the tomcat server on centos machine,please tell me

Comment: Does this link help?

http://serverfault.com/questions/14838/installing-tomcat-on-centos-5?rq=1

Thanks

Comment: not getting correct answer :( :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good article here, well written and detailed;

http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos

Comment: i tried this but am getting some errors.can you please clarify my doubts pls pls

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests no research at all. I'd delete your question if I could.

[Google Search Engine is awesome](https://www.google.hu/search?q=centos%20repository%20tomcat)

Comment: getting some errors @David

Comment: r u there...????